# Prove the operators $T+U$ and $U$ have the same eigenvalues where $T$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space on $\mathbb{C}$, and $T$ a nilpotent operator on $V$. 
Let $U$ be in $L(V)$ s.t. $UT = TU$. Prove that the operators $T+U$ and $U$ have the same eigenvalues.

So far I know that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $x^n$, but I'm having a difficult time moving forward from there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since $T$ and $U$ commute, they are simultaneously triangularizable (we are over $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: @julien You can probably add that comment as an answer.

Comment: You can read about (simultaneous) triangularizability [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Triangularisability). But this is overkill if you don't know about that, especially if you just want to prove that the eigenvalues are the same.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think we all agree that this is obvious for $T=0$, so let's assume that $T\neq0$ for the rest of this post.

First, let's look at the commutativity relation between $T$ and $U$. Since $TU=UT$, if we pick an eigenvector $v$ of $U$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, what can we say about $UT\left(v\right)$? When looking at this, just remember that $UT\left(v\right)=U\left(T\left(v\right)\right)$, and you should see what's happening when you mess around using the commutativity.

Next, for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $U$, let's select an eigenvector $v$. Since $T$ is nilpotent, there exists $n$ so that $T^{n-1}\neq0$ and $T^{n}=0$. So, what can you say about $\left(T+U\right)\left(T^{n-1}v\right)$? This should be one direction of the proof for you.

The other direction shouldn't be all that hard. Just show that $T+U$ commutes with $T$ and see where you can get from there using (modified versions of) the arguments in the previous two paragraphs.